# Strange behavior with Array deconstruction in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I've ran into situations where the following throws an `undefined` error:

```
...
(str) => {
  const [first, second] = str.split('.');
  // throws an undefined error
  // (can't find a .next of undefined? -- this may not be related)
}
...
```

So, I convert to the following and it works:

```
...
(str) => {
  const temp = str.split('.');
  const first = temp[0];
  const second = temp[1];
}
...
```

Strangely enough, if I convert the `const` to `let`, it works:

```
...
(str) => {
  let temp = str.split('.');
  let [first, second] = temp;
}
...
```

Node `v6.9.1`

Comment: What node version? It works for me with node v8.x.

Comment: Node `v6.9.1` ..

Comment: What are the situations where it throws undefined?

Comment: What is the input for which it throws the exception for const but not for let?

Comment: I just tested with node v6.5.0 and v6.10.0 and it works fine with those too.

Comment: Yeah, I have tested it as well in browsers, which work well, but have ran into situations where a long string needing to be split in this fashion throws an error

Comment: @Detuned can you provide any **actual** example of where it throws an error - with exact Node version and exact input (without mysterious "long string" generalizations)? Please post some code that could actually be run and tested. Thanks.

Comment: @mscdex I also tested it on several Node versions in Travis (see my answer) and it works fine every time with no exception on any version that supports array destructuring (from 6.0.0). Since the original poster cannot post an actual example of where that error happens and for what input, I would consider this question to be either a hoax or just misinformation.

Comment: As mentioned, it's hard to replicate outside of the project. We've noticed it several times come and go, so we've opted to use the traditional array accessor syntax. I'll go ahead and record a session....

Answer (score 1):

### This works fine

Tested on Node:

- 6.0.0
- 6.9.0
- **6.9.1**
- 6.9.5
- 6.11.1
- 7.0.0
- 7.10.1
- 8.0.0
- 8.1.4

See the project on GitHub:

- https://github.com/rsp/node-array-destructuring-test

See the test results on Travis:

- https://travis-ci.org/rsp/node-array-destructuring-test

The original poster was asked multiple times for actual example of data that shows this behavior but failed to do so. Me and other people specifically asked for Node version and input example for which that error happens and for which the error doesn't happen when the `const` is changed to `let`. Since no such example was provided I would consider this question to be misleading and the phenomenon that it describes to not actually take place.

Comment: Yes, we've done a great deal of testing outside of our application and it seems to work. Again, we've seen this come and go and have opted for the traditional array accessor syntax. I'll record a session within our application for review...